# DKIM validation fails when SPF record is present

Tags: dns, spf, dkim

I have recently set up TXT records for DKIM and SPF for a domain. SPF alone works great, and so does DKIM. But when both SPF and DKIM is configured, DKIM validation fails. I have tried a variety of test tools, e.g. https://www.mail-tester.com and http://dkimvalidator.com

Here are the two TXT records:

v=DKIM1; k=rsa; g=*; s=em
ail; h=sha1; t=s; p=MIGfM
A0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNAD
CBiQKBgQCxTm3jBuuENFRel1L
z5NEc2LcYcKDOf7GRNd7wLMX2
9ZEM0wwuM/H6MBvbeXgltRqkN
Z9hum+4jhtruwbngxPYAsk/lf
kRrlBNJROjikybsmN6kGovbI3
oU77Vv9jHJ6i5tgp9Th8KqaSy
AiTdS/mRfE8AfrIghIaIqffdS
7+GqQIDAQAB;

v=spf1 mx -all

I'm stock with this one, so any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

- Thanks

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. SPF makes no changes to the message headers or body that might cause a DKIM failure, and DKIM doesn't do any SPF DNS lookups that might be affected by SPF. DMARC is the only thing that connects the two, which you don't mention. You need to be clearer about what your problem is.

Comment: You do have a typo in your DKIM record: `s=em ail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchro > Thanks for helping me out.
It don't see the typo. If I do a "dig" in a terminal, the attribute looks fine. I can't rule out that I actually had a typo earlier.

However, I've found the problem.
Rather than using [selector]._domainkey.domain.com, I used domain.com.
Obviously that doesn't work.

- Thanks again